# linear searching an array of class objects

Tags: c++, arrays, linear-search

I have a linear search algorithm set up to search through an array of class objects it works but the output does not match, when i search for a particular name in the array the 1st and third values int the array are found but the second value is not found.

below is my code thanks for your help.

```
int linsearch(string val)
{
    for (int j=0; j <= 3; j++)
    {
        if  (player[j].getLastName()==val)
         return j ;         
    }
        return 1 ;
}   


void showinfo()
{
    string search;
    int found ;


    cout << "Please Enter The Player's Last Name : " ;
    cin >> search ;

    found=linsearch(search);

    if (found==1)
    {
        cout << "\n There is no player called " << search ;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\n First Name : " << player[found].getFirstName() << "\n" << "Last Name : " << player[found].getLastName() <<
            "\n" << "Age : " << player[found].getAge() << "\n" << "Current Team : " << player[found].getCurrentTeam() << 
            "\n" << "Position : " << player[found].getPosition() << "\n" << "Status :  " << player[found].getStatus()  << "\n\n";
    }

    cin.get() ;

    menu() ;

}
```

Answer (score 6):

Because you are using the index of the second element as a "not found" code:

```
int linsearch(string val)
{
    for (int j=0; j <= 3; j++)
    {
        if  (player[j].getLastName()==val)
         return j ;         
    }
        return 1 ;
}
```

You should return something that cannot be an index, for instance `-1`. Or better still, use [std::find_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

Comment: May I suggest to the OP he uses -1 instead of 1.

Answer (score 2):

The second element's  index is identical to the value which flags the "not found" condition.

Use an invalid index like `-1` to flag the "not found" condition:

```
int linsearch(string val)
{
    for (int j=0; j <= 3; j++)
    {
        if  (player[j].getLastName()==val)
         return j ;         
    }

    return -1;
}
```

and then check for `-1` in the calling function:

```
if (found==-1)
{
    cout << "\n There is no player called " << search ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do something like this... return any other integer like '-1' if not found

```
int linsearch(string val)
{
for (int j=0; j <= 3; j++)
{
    if  (player[j].getLastName()==val)
     return j ;         
}
    return -1 ;
} 


void showinfo()
{
string search;
int found ;


cout << "Please Enter The Player's Last Name : " ;
cin >> search ;

found=linsearch(search);

if (found == -1)
{
    cout << "\n There is no player called " << search ;
}

[...]
```